# Rewrite .htaccess resulting in 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make my url look good but for some reasons it is not working what could be the problem here

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view?wall=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Above rewrite should resolve like this `http://website.com/view/apartment-wallpapers/1247`

***Alternatively***

Preferably I want to make my url to look like this but it's also resulting in

`http://lifistudy.com/asus-red-903.html`

.htaccess rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /view?wall=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Note: using ***openlitespeed*** and all .htaccess rules are working

Comment: Hi, I have posted an answer hope you will find a solution for it. if you find this as helpful pls, mark it as correct.

Comment: @SamirLakhani question is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your rewrite rule. You're using `([^/]*)` which is incorrect syntax use `(.*)` and your rewrite rule will work perfectly.

Comment: Ahh great it work superb 
RewriteRule page/(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /view?wall=$1&page=$2[L]